# Compare rows of matrix and choose ones which have less NAs

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset

This question will be summarized by example.

```
mat1 <- matrix(nrow = 6, ncol =40, data=rnorm(240,0,1))
mat1[1, 30:40] <- NA
mat1[2, 13:40] <- NA
mat1[3, 1:15] <- NA
mat1[4, 35:40] <- NA
mat1[5, 35:40] <- NA
mat1[6, 20:40] <- NA


criteria.mat <- matrix(nrow = 6,ncol =2)
criteria.mat[1,] = c(1,2)
criteria.mat[2,] = c(1,3)
criteria.mat[3,] = c(2,3)
criteria.mat[4,] = c(2,4)
criteria.mat[5,] = c(2,5)
criteria.mat[6,] = c(4,5)
```

The criteria matrix species the rows that need to be compared in mat1.  We need to compare rows 1 and 2, 1 and 3, 2 and 3 etc (all the way through). If one row has less NAs than the other, it should be placed in a yet to be created 'output matrix'. In this case, when comparing rows 1 and 2 we would choose row1. when we compare rows 1 and 3, we choose 1. comparing 2 and 3, we choose 3. comparing rows 2 and 4, we choose 4, comparing 2 and 5 we choose 5. Now in the case of 4 and 5 (when rows have equal numbers of NAs), we must choose the one that was not already been selected (in this case neither). If both have been selected remove  either one of them (So in the example i'm removing row 5, but you could also remove row 4). The output matrix consists of all the rows selected.

In this case:

`Output.Mat <- rbind(mat1[1,], mat1[3,], mat1[4,])`

is there a way to do this via a function? Perhaps with a rowSums command?

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this would be

```
#Calculate rowwise NA values present in 1st column of criteria.mat
val1 <- rowSums(is.na(mat1[criteria.mat[, 1], ])) 
#Calculate rowwise NA values present in 2st column of criteria.mat
val2 <- rowSums(is.na(mat1[criteria.mat[, 2], ]))

#Compare them and select the indices with lowest NA values
inds <- unique(ifelse(val1 < val2, criteria.mat[, 1], criteria.mat[, 2]))

#Get indices which have equal NA values
values <- which(val1 == val2)
#Select the indices which were not already selected in inds
final_value <- c(inds, setdiff(criteria.mat[values, ], inds))
#Subset from mat1
mat1[final_value, ]
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a proposed solution to loop over all combinations.

```
mat1 <- matrix(nrow = 6, ncol =40, data=rnorm(240,0,1))
mat1[1, 30:40] <- NA
mat1[2, 13:40] <- NA
mat1[3, 1:15] <- NA
mat1[4, 35:40] <- NA
mat1[5, 35:40] <- NA
mat1[6, 20:40] <- NA

#Store the number of NA per raw
num_nans=c()
for (i in c(1:nrow(mat1)))
{
  num_nans = c(num_nans,length(which(is.na(mat1[i,]))))
}

#To store final results
mat2 <- matrix(nrow = 0, ncol =40)

#To store the raw we already added
added_raw=c()
#Loop over all combination
for (i in c(1:(nrow(mat1)-1)))
{
  for (j in c((i+1):nrow(mat1)))
  {
    if(num_nans[i]<num_nans[j])
    {
      mat2=rbind(mat2,mat1[i,])
      added_raw=c(added_raw,i)
    }
    else if(num_nans[i]>num_nans[j])
    {
      mat2=rbind(mat2,mat1[j,])
      added_raw=c(added_raw,j)

    }
    #Case they are equal, add i if not already added
    else if(!(i %in% added_raw))
    {
      mat2=rbind(mat2,mat1[i,])
      added_raw=c(added_raw,i)
    }
    #Case they are equal, i already added before, add j if not already added
    else if(!(j %in% added_raw))
    {
      mat2=rbind(mat2,mat1[j,])
      added_raw=c(added_raw,j)
    }
    #Case both already added, add one of them
    else
    {
      mat2=rbind(mat2,mat1[i,])
      added_raw=c(added_raw,i)
    }
  }
}
```